# Filter PowerShell output values

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> Get-EC2Instance |%{ $_.RunningInstance } | Select-Object InstanceId,ImageID,@{Name='TagValues'; Expression={ ($_.Tags |%{ $_.Value }) }}

InstanceId         ImageId             TagValues
----------         -------             ---------
i-230151d5         ami-20224b10        Scott
i-8c80f27a         ami-e7527ed7        {landscape123, test123}
i-3d3195cb         ami-0b5f073b        temp
```

How do I modify my command so only the "landscape*" is filtered and displayed?

```
InstanceId         ImageId             TagValues
----------         -------             ---------
i-8c80f27a         ami-e7527ed7        landscape123
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in some cases the `Tags` property contains multiple values. Change your calculated property like this to restrict it to a single value:

```psh
@{Name='TagValues'; Expression={$_.Tags | select -Expand Value | select -First 1}}
```

And add a filter to restrict your results to the objects with a specific tag value:

```psh
Get-EC2Instance |
  select -Expand RunningInstance |
  select InstanceId, ImageID,
         @{n='TagValues';e={$_.Tags | select -Expand Value | select -First 1}} |
  ? { $_.TagValues -eq 'landscape123' }
```

If you want to keep multiple tags for an instance, do this instead:

```psh
Get-EC2Instance |
  select -Expand RunningInstance |
  select InstanceId, ImageID,
         @{n='TagValues';e={$_.Tags | select -Expand Value}} |
  ? { @($_.TagValues) -contains 'landscape123' }
```

If you need a partial match on one of the tags, do something like this:

```psh
Get-EC2Instance |
  select -Expand RunningInstance |
  select InstanceId, ImageID,
         @{n='TagValues';e={$_.Tags | select -Expand Value}} |
  ? { $_.TagValues | ? { $_ -like 'landscape*' } }
```